# What is .<format> argument for?

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

- Django==1.11
- django-extensions==1.9.7

  ```
  /api/userprofiles/<pk>/   poinkbackend.apps.userprofiles.api.viewsets.UserProfileViewset  api:userprofile-detail
  /api/userprofiles/<pk>\.<format>/ poinkbackend.apps.userprofiles.api.viewsets.UserProfileViewset  api:userprofile-detail
  /a
  ```

Docs say

> show_urls - Displays the url routes that are defined in your project. Very crude at this point.

I had searched with `format` keyword. But the results are not related to my question.

Does it stand for `?format=json` argument?

I had tried replacing json by html, xml. I got error in return.

**Reference:**
http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html?highlight=show_urls

Comment: Well really what you need to do is figure out what `poinkbackend` is and go look at it's source. In it's API view it'll tell you what the kwarg `format` is expected to do and that'll explain it.

Comment: I have never looked to `format` in the view. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that URL pattern, `format` is a keyword argument in the URL pattern (unlike `?format=json` where it's in the querystring). A matching URL would be:

```
/api/userprofiles/5.json/
```

Comment: Never known it has this pattern too. I normally use `/api/userprofiles/5/?format=json`